# How to Change image on UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, copy, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on SMS application for Iphone .. 
And now i want to change image of my chat bubble on longpress ( like while i copy the contant )..

i have this code ..

```
if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {


        [self becomeFirstResponder];

        //NSIndexPath *pressedIndexPath = [tblOutgoingMessagesRecords indexPathForRowAtPoint:[longPressRecognizer locationInView:tblOutgoingMessagesRecords]];

        NSIndexPath *pressedIndexPath = [tblOutgoingMessagesRecords indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)longPressRecognizer.view];
        if (pressedIndexPath && (pressedIndexPath.row != NSNotFound) && (pressedIndexPath.section != NSNotFound)) 
        {
            [self becomeFirstResponder];
            NSLog(@" Presssed on Copy ");
```

I just want to change my Chat bubble color to blue while i lonpress it for copy ..
As like in iphone default has done i want to do same ... Can any one help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to check if the *state* is *UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized* to change the Chat bubble's color,

```
if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

    // Change Chat bubble's color to blue
}
```

Comment: how ? m using image for that chat bubble .. I want to replace it on onhold(long press) .. so how can i do ??

Answer (score 1):

check color to red when long press gesture begin condition

```
if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{


    [self becomeFirstResponder];
   // change image from  here
    //NSIndexPath *pressedIndexPath = [tblOutgoingMessagesRecords indexPathForRowAtPoint:[longPressRecognizer locationInView:tblOutgoingMessagesRecords]];

    NSIndexPath *pressedIndexPath = [tblOutgoingMessagesRecords indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)longPressRecognizer.view];
    if (pressedIndexPath && (pressedIndexPath.row != NSNotFound) && (pressedIndexPath.section != NSNotFound)) 
    {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@" Presssed on Copy ");
  }
}
else  if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
 {

    //load original  image here...

   }
```

Comment: its not working buddy ... !! it recognize that its copy but image not change .. How could i change image in else if ..